# Visual Studio Code Analyzer Gives Nonsense Warnings

Tags: visual-studio-2019

In Solution Explorer under Dependencies>Analyzers I have Microsoft.AspNetCore.Anayzers and three issues listed.

- ASP0000: Do not call 'IServiceCollection.BuildServiceProvider' in 'ConfigureServices'
- ASP0001: Authorization middleware is incorrectly configured
- MVC1005: Cannot use UseMvc with Endpoint Routing

However, the first and last do not make any sense because the issues don't exist in my Startup.cs. The messages do not specify a file or line number that they're referring to.

```
public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            // Deliberately blank to see if the message goes away. It does not.
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
                // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
                app.UseHsts();
            }
            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    //pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
                    pattern: "{action=Index}",
                    defaults: new { controller = "Home" });
            });
        }
    }
```

I've restarted Visual Studio, cleaned the solution, done Analyze Code and Cleanup>Run Code Analysis on Solution, run VS as admin, deleted .vs folder, deleted obj folder. It looks like the Analyzer part of Solution Explorer is completely broken as it's complaining about code that does not exist.

**Is there a way to reset the analyzers or am I missing something obvious here?**